# It is possible to read NFC when app is in background?

Tags: android, nfc

I need to build an application that listens to NFC tags in the background. Is it possible ?.
Solution :
The application runs a thread which is a socket server with which the web application connects. I need to send read NFC tags to the web application via websocket.

I will be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, but with limitations. See the docs for more information:

#### Advanced NFC -> **Working with tag technologies and the ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED intent**

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html

Essentially, working with tag technologies and the `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent. When a device scans a tag that has NDEF data on it, but could not be mapped to a MIME or URI, the tag dispatch system tries to start an activity with the `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent.

You can then register your app to listen for these intents.

Comment: Does that intent have all the data contained in the nfc?

Comment: @PedroRomanoBarbosa I ended up not going with this solution, but needed it for research. I can see here from the docs `onNewIntent` gets the tag from the Intent `val tagFromIntent: Tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)`... thus I'd be certain that's the whole tag read.